# What are the rules for troop kills in towers during KvK?

Tags: king-of-avalon-dragon-warfare

During Excalibur Invasion (KvK), invading kingdoms can attack the throne and the towers ([video](https://youtu.be/ZcudOMSM9yw?t=50)).

However sometimes the troops are killed instantly after defeat even while protecting the tower. Shouldn't be the same game logic when you're protecting alliance tower or a castle, so the troops are hospitalised?

How many towers do you need to control to avoid instant kills and get your troops safely to the hospitals? Basically what are the rules to avoid instant kills during KvK?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, all battles in Avalon and towers are considered an attack on both sides, as you can notice both sides dragons have assault skills active, so the troops go to the hospital only within wounded conversion. That is based on our conclusions, since there is no official info regarding the game logic.